# How can I append dates to only files with txt extension?

Tags: vbscript

A couple of days, you guys helped me with the bug I was having with the following code:

```
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
Set fldr = FSO.GetFolder("C:\Ebooks\DRY\") 
curYr=Year(Now)
For Each fil In fldr.Files 
    If LCase( Right( fil.Name, 4 ) ) = ".zip" Then 
        zipFilePath = fil.Path 
        temp = file.Name 
        temp = Left( temp, LEN(temp) - 4 ) ' remove the .zip 
        temp = Split( temp, "_" ) ' split base name away from month-day-year 
        temp = (temp(ubound(temp))) ' get just month-day-year 
        temp = Split( temp, "-" ) ' get month day and year separately 
        mn = CINT(temp(0)) ' get the month number 
        dirName = MonthName(mn,True) & temp(2) ' True means get 3 letter abbrev for month 
        objZip.UnPack zipFilePath, "D:\ACS\Current\" 
        FSO.MoveFile zipFilePath, "D:\ACS\" & curYr & "\" & dirName & "\" & fil.Name       
    End If 
Next
```

The script works fine. All unzipped files are moved to a folder called Current and the original zip file is moved to a folder ACSCurrentYear.

The unzipped files have 2 different extensions, pdf and txt.

Between Monday through Friday, the code works fine in that everyday, we extract the contents of the of txt files into the database.

However, on weekends, since the txt files have the same name, they are overwritten, thereby causing us to lose data. The pdf files are not overwritten because the names are always unique.

What I would like to do is append currentdate and time to only files with txt extension.

I think I have the code to do that but not sure how to integrate it into the script I posted above.

Here is the bit I would like to integrate.

```
strDay = Day(now)
strMonth = Month(now)
strYear = Year(now)

strHour = Hour(now)
strMinute = Minute(now)
strSecond = Second(now)

 datFinal = strYear & "/" & strMonth & "/" & strDay & " " & strHour & ":" & strMinute & ":" & strSecond
```

'now, append date to any file with txt extension.

```
 if lcase(FSO.GetExtensionName(fil.Name)) = "txt" then
  fil.Name = "datFinal.txt"
```

How can I handle this?

Even better, can I add a line of code to the code I posted to NOT allow the txt files to be overwritten?

Thanks very much for your assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either make a new subfolder under "D:\ACS\Current\"  each day and extract to that folder like

```
date_folder = strYear & strMonth & strDay
FSO.CreateFolder ("D:\ACS\Current\" & date_folder)
objZip.UnPack zipFilePath, "D:\ACS\Current\" & date_folder
```

or

unzip to a temporary folder and move the files there to "D:\ACS\Current\" while applying your logic so they don't overwrite each other.

Comment: you'r welcome, i suggest to pad the result of strMonth and strDay to get a nice sortable subfolder list, so 20120518 instead of 2012518